# kernel.cpp showing error and Makefile error while making kernel.o

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, operating-system, kernel

THE ERROR IS:(I undderstand the warnings please just correct the errors)

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Ohm Os# make kernel.o

g++ -m32 -o kernel.o -c kernel.cpp

kernel.cpp: In function ‘void kernelMain(void*, unsigned int)’:

kernel.cpp:27:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 

‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

     printf("HELLO WORLD");
                         ^
kernel.cpp:31:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^

Makefile:9: recipe for target 'kernel.o' failed

make: *** [kernel.o] Error 1
```

THIS IS MY KERNEL.CPP:

```
void printf(char* str)
{
    unsigned short* VideoMemory = (unsigned short*)0xb8000;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}

void kernelMain(void* multiboot_structure, unsigned int magicnumber)
{
    printf("HELLO WORLD");
    while(1)
}
```

ALSO MY Makefile:

```
GPPPARAMS = -m32
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386
ojects = loader.o kernel.o

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel with your `make` variables and suffix rules? There are perfectly good ones by default that can be easily adapted to most purposes. They also have the advantage of being universally understood which helps the maintainability of your makefiles.

Comment: Missing something at the end of : `while(1)`. Typo?

Comment: And yeah, you'll probably survive the warning. But why is `printf` expecting a `char*`? That is weird to see in a compiler complaining over a `const char *` to `char *` conversion. Are you trying to use an old standard library with a modern compiler?

Comment: I am working on an operating system i am 18 and thx for the help everyone

Comment: I don't recommend coding an OS kernel in a language you are not very familiar with. Look also on [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kernel.cpp:31:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
 }

try: 
while(1);

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you understand the consequences of the warning?

As for the error, you seem to be mixing the syntax for [do while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) and [while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while)

You need to either use

```
while (condition)
  statement
```

or

```
do
  statement
while (condition)
```

Comment: Actually, I think OP wants an infinite loop to keep the program from exiting.

Comment: I think so too, in which case the condition is something that is always true.